# RDP two factor authentication with login, pass and self-signed certificate

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

Is there any way to configure remote desktop authentication to require not only the windows login and password, but also a self-signed certificate to be installed on the client machine?

All windows users are configured in the Active Directory.